# c warning: use of const variable in a constant expression is non-standard in C

Tags: c, warnings

I'm getting this warning when trying to initialize an array to a constant size.

**#2170-D use of a const variable in a constant expression is nonstandard in C**

```
#file.h
typedef struct {
    // LED Blink Pattern
    .....
} LEDSeq

void addError(LEDSeq);
void runLEDErrors();
....

#file.c
const uint8_t MAXERRORS = 4;
LEDSeq errors[MAXERRORS];
uint8_t errorsLength = 0;
....
```

Essentially it's a bit of code that is going to loop over LED error sequences that are added during run time. I've got to use a fixed size array because realloc isn't available in my environment. The code all works. I'm just wondering why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Were that automatic array var it would technically be a VLA. That your C compiler allows it globally is both a blessing and a curse.

Comment: The code is valid C++ however (albeit somewhat inelegant C++).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `const` object is not a constant in C but a read-only object. An array declared at file scope (or any array with static storage duration) has to have a constant expression as its number of elements.

This is valid:

```
#define MAXERRORS 4
LEDSeq errors[MAXERRORS];
```